# Are questions asking for "part of speech" all on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Some questions on [part of speech (POS)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/part-of-speech) are interesting and useful to me. However, honestly I don't understand how the linked question [What part of speech is the word “very” in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328502/what-part-of-speech-is-the-word-very-in-this-sentence) could have survived without getting closed.

The purpose of this question is not asking ELU users to close-vote it. I am asking it to see if there is something I am missing or grey area (grammatical) that can justify the question.

Comment: Are you asking if part of speech questions are always on topic, or are you asking why this particular question did not get closed?

Comment: @MετάEd Maybe both.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason why the linked question was not closed.
Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
That being said, there is no solid existing answer explaining how "very" works there.